# How to call a UIView method in my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a method to create a rectangle in my custom uiview and I want to call it in my UIViewController.I am trying to use UITapGestureRecognizer in my UIViewController and check if a point in the rectangle is called.

rectangle in my custom uiview ( myView.m )

```
- (CGRect) myRect
{
    return CGRectMake(10, 10, self.bounds.size.height - 20, self.bounds.size.height - 20);
}
```

UITapGestureRecognizer method in my MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
[self.PlayDraw setNeedsDisplay];

}


- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([self.PlayDraw myRect],point)) {
        NSLog(@"touched");

    }
```

and I get an error for [self.PlayDraw myRect] that says

> No visible @interface for 'MyViewController' declares the
>   selector 'myRect'

and here is my MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{

}
- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet myView *PlayDraw;
@end
```

Comment: Just so you know convention says that your Class `myView` should be `MyView` and your variable `PlayDraw` should  be `playDraw`. Classes started with an upper case and variables start with lower case this is to stop any confusion in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your myView.h file add:

```
- (CGRect) myRect;
```

You have to expose this method to other classes.

Comment: ohh thanks! totally forgot it! one more question when i use UIView *rectView = [[myView alloc] init];
    self.view = rectView;  in my loadView or viewdidload then the IBOUTLET's made using storyboard dont show.what is the problem?

Comment: What's the question? You should use [self.view addSubview:aGraphView]; In this example.

Comment: basically i want to use both custom uiview and storyboard interface builder

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand you. What do you mean that the IBOutled don't show? Have you added UIView in storyboard, with connection(IBOutlet) and after that you change it in viewDidLoad and nothing happened?

Comment: like for example when i do @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Info; then the label doesn't  show when I add the uiview to my UIViewController programmatically using loadView instead of adding UIView in storyboard.So in short: does the UIView in storyboard get over overridden when i call loadView? and so should i just add the uiview using storyboard?

Comment: How do you load the view programatically? maybe you override label view? Try move the code to viewDidLoad instead of loadView.

Comment: UIView *myview = [[myView alloc] init];
 self.view = myview;  the problem is that when i use custom uiview in my UIViewController then nothing in viewDidLoad gets updated.I have a slider in my UIViewController's viewDidLoad and it's tracker doesn't move at all.

Comment: Try [self.view addSubview:myview];